# indexing 'all' 2d array python different from single indexing

Tags: python, arrays

I have a meshgrid array of latitudes and longitudes and if I do the following:

```
print(new_lats[:][0]
```

I get an array with all different latitude values. Great. Now for the longitudes:

```
print(new_lons[0][0])
print(new_lons[1][0])
```

I get the results

```
-81.53
-81.52
```

Therefore, it would appear that the first index controls the different longitude values. However, If I do:

```
print(new_lons[:][0])
```

I get an array all of the value of -81.53. So it would seem that the 2nd index might actually alter longitude values:

```
print(new_lons[0][0])
print(new_lons[0][1])
```

I get the results

```
-81.53
-81.53
```

Getting the min and max from the array:

```
np.amin(new_lons)
np.amax(new_lons)
```

will yield

```
-81.53
-78.52
```

How can I get a single line of longitude values similar to how I indexed the latitudes, and why wouldn't it be similar?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include an array of sample data and desired output?

Comment: `new_lats[:]` returns the whole array, so you can equally well use `new_lats`. Then `new_lats[0]` gives the 0-th row of `new_lats`. I guess what you want is the 0-th column of `new_lons` which can be obtained using `new_lons[:, 0]`.